# Make DockableContent Stack in AvalonDock

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

How do I make the initial startup state of two dockable content panes stack instead of being tabbed using AvalonDock?

```
                <ad:DockableContent x:Name="toolsContent" Title="Materials" Selector.IsSelected="True">
                    <Canvas Background="White">
                    </Canvas>
                </ad:DockableContent>
                <ad:DockableContent x:Name="properties" Title="Properties">
                    <Canvas Background="White">
                    </Canvas>                        
                </ad:DockableContent>
```

So in this case the app will load as two dockable contents as tabs, one hiding behind the other. Whereas I want one panel above the other (stacked) not behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 2 `<ad:DockableContent` elements are now inside 1 `<ad:DockablePane` element.
AvalonDock creates a tab inside the Pane for each piece of Content.

You need to make 2 separate `<ad:DockablePane` elements
- both inside a `<ad:ResizingPanel Orientation="Vertical">` -
with 1 `<ad:DockableContent` element in each.